# Shorthand 'if' is throwing a syntax error

Tags: python, if-statement, shorthand

I have an argparser that has a verbose flag and I'm trying to minimize the amount I have to write to get the verbose output.

This works as expected:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
verbose=True
print(verbose)
if verbose:
    print("verbose output")
```

outputs:

```
$ ./example.py
True
verbose output
```

but

```
#!/usr/bin/python
verbose=True
print(verbose)
print("verbose output") if verbose
```

throws an error:

```
$ ./example.py
  File "./example.py", line 5
    print("verbose output") if verbose
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I thought the python had the `statement if condition else condition` syntax? Have I made some mistake?

```
$ python -V
Python 3.6.2
```

Comment: There is no shorthand `if test` syntax, no. There is only the *conditional expression* `<true_expr> if <test_expr> else <false_expr>`.

Comment: It has the `expression if condition else  expression` syntax. It doesn't have `statement if condition`.

Comment: You should not use that here, there is no need to 'shorten' anything. If you must, put the expression on the same line as the `if` test: `if verbose: print('verbose output')`.

Comment: You may be thinking of Perl, which does have such a statement modifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python `if` [ternary operator syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#is-there-an-equivalent-of-c-s-ternary-operator) requires an `else`, like so:

```
x = 2 if y < 5 else 4
```

Answer (score 1):

For verbose output like this you're best off using the [Logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.debug('foo') # prints nothing
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.debug('foo') # prints 'DEBUG:name:foo'
```

You can update the format of the string it uses, links are in the documentation.

Comment: `logging` is an option, but not necessarily the appropriate one to simply control when a `print` function actually produces output. See https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#when-to-use-logging.

Comment: I've read that, yes - and I think this is exactly what it's for. "Report events that occur during normal operation of a program (e.g. for status monitoring or fault investigation" - that's really what verbose output is for.

Comment: I think of it this way: `print` is for implementing what a program does, logging is for describing how it does it.

Comment: Depends what the OP wants verbose messages for, I suppose

Answer (score -1):

Define an alias for `print` that either prints its argument or does nothing, depending on the value of `verbose`:

```
if verbose:
    print_verbose = print
else:
    def print_verbose(*args, **kwargs):
        pass

print_verbose("This only gets printed if verbose is True")
```

Comment: This seems to recreate the logging module, but in a harder-to-follow way

Comment: It's not recreating the logging module. The logging module provides *many* ways to modify what exactly is output, where it is output to, and whether or not it gets output at all (especially if logging configuration is loaded from a configuration file). The only thing I am allowing to be configured is whether or not a `print` function is called. If it *is* called, what it does is still under full control of the code as written.